sql error, Saying theres no relations between tables but I cant figure out why
I have a database for a DnD builder webpage.
We want to make an application that when the user selects a radio on the webpage it will pull the corresponding information from the database and display the compiled data on the webpage so that the user can see the end result of however many choices without too much busywork.
The Database is sql, and I'm currently working on the models for it with Sequelize.
However, the models are currently the trouble.
I'm extremely inexperienced, so I fear this mistake is a very simple one. Because this is the error code being thrown out on my console.
length: 105,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42P01',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended',
sql: 'ALTER TABLE "Race"  ADD FOREIGN KEY ("subrace_id") REFERENCES "Subrace" ("id");',       
parameters: undefined
ubrace_id") REFERENCES "Subrace" ("id");',
sql: 'ALTER TABLE "Race"  ADD FOREIGN KEY ("subrace_id") REFERENCES "Subrace" ("id");',
parameters: {}                                 race_id") REFERENCES "Subrace" ("id");',
> }

This is the subrace model
const  { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../config/connection.js');


class Subrace extends Model {}

Subrace.init(
    {
        id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         allowNull: false,
         primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        skills_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'Skills',
                key: 'id',
                unique: false,
            },
        },
    }, 
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        modelName: 'Subrace'
    }
    


);

module.exports = Subrace; 


This is the race model
const  { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../config/connection.js');


class Race extends Model {}

Race.init(
    {
        id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         allowNull: false,
         primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        subrace_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'Subrace',
                key: 'id'
            },
        },
        skills_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'Skills',
                key: 'id'
            },
        },
    }, 
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        modelName: 'Race'
    }
    


);

module.exports = Race; 



I think the error is coming in in how I've made the index.
Race.hasOne(Subrace, {
  foreignKey: "subrace_id",
});

Subrace.belongsTo(Race, {
  foreignKey: "race_id",
});

This is presently how they're coded in. If I've overlooked any code or information that's important or helpful please tell me.
I've looked for syntax errors and tried moving the code structure around. I'd heard if they're made in the wrong order that can be the cause of this issue.

I think you have the foreign key relationship backwards. A race can have many subraces. So Subrace should have a race_id that referenes Race.id, not the way you've written it.
